# What is the difference between void method and return this

Tags: java, return, this, void, setter

```
Class Player {
Player setName(String name){
this.name = name;
return this;

// or

void setName(String name){
this.name = name;
}}
```

Hi. What is the difference if I use the method with "void" or "return this" statement? Why the "return this" statement exists, if it does the same?

Comment: java is pass by value. If you return this is is like you are returning pointer. in return advantage is you can return reference created in method.
refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 5):

> Why the "return this" statement exists, if it does the same?

They don't remotely do the same thing.

A void method has no return value. That means you can't use the return value (for instance, you can't assign it to a variable).

A method with a return value has a return value. In the particular case you've mentioned, `return this`, it's returning a reference to the object that the method was called on, so you can (potentially) use that reference — by assigning it to a variable, by calling another method on it, etc. This is useful for *[fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)* (ones that allow you to do a lot of chaining):

```
theObject.doThis().thenDoThat().thenDoSomethingElse();
```

If it were `void` instead, you'd have to write that like this:

```
theObject.doThis();
theObject.thenDoThat();
theObject.thenDoSomethingElse();
```

Probably the most famous example of this<sup>1</sup> is [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) of object construction, because it means you don't need a variable:

```
Thingy t = new ThingyBuilder()
    .withFoo("foo")
    .withBar("bar")
    .withBaz("baz")
    .build();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Most famous outside web development circles, that is; *inside* web development circles, the most famous example would be jQuery's API: `$("div").css("color", "green").text("Good");`

Comment: thank you for the brilliant answer. I was already reading about the chaining or rather fluent interfaces but did not really get how it works. it's just pretty hard to understand material learning all time alone.

Answer (score 3):

The first is used for chaining methods (builder pattern)  while the second is a plain vanilla setter method

Answer (score 3):

When you `return this`, you return a `Player` instance.

More commonly used in the Builder Pattern, this returns a Player with the name of Joe.

```
Player p = new Player().setName("Bob").setName("Joe");
```

Using the `void` method, you cannot do the second `setName`. In order to rename the player, you'd have to get the first instance of the player object, then call `setName` again on the following line.

Obviously, a simple example, but is more useful when you have lots of setters like so

```
new Player()
  .setName("Bob")
  .setAge(42)
  .setGender("male")
```

Though, I think the convention is to use `withX` rather than `setX` here.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `this` allows chaining such as:

`player.setName(...).setSomethingElse(...)`

When returning `void` there is no object reference so chaining is not possible and you have code such as:

`player.setName(...);
player.setSomethingElse(...);`

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why one can ask how returning nothing and returning something could be the same. Anyway: no, returning something and returning nothing is not the same.

Returning **this** is mainly used to allow for "fluent" interfaces, so that users of your classes can write

```
yourObject.setFoo(foo).setBar(bar).doSomething();
```

instead of

```
yourObject.setFoo(foo);
yourObject.setBar(bar);
yourObject.doSomething();
```

If that helps with readability probably depends on the style you and the other people working with that source code are used to. One typical pattern that heavily relies on writing such code is the [Builder pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html).